# How to know what element triggered the openind of a bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events

I have two product dropdowns in a form. If the selected option is the first one (with value -1) a modal open in which the user can save a new product.

On modal close I update both dropdown and want to auto select the new product only in the dropdown that triggered the modal open. I already managed to do all the logic around the saving, updating and autoselecting. Problem is that now I autoselect on both dropdowns and not only on the one that triggered.

This is how I'm opening the modal:

```
if (select.value == '-1') {
    let modal = document.getElementById('newProductModal');        
    // set some properties on the modal
    $(modal).modal('show');
```

And this is the click eventlistener on the submit button:

```
document.getElementById('saveNewProduct').addEventListener('click', function (e) {  
    // some stuff  
    document.querySelectorAll("select[id$='product']").forEach(item => {
        populateProducts(item, data.id);
    })
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a variable to keep track of which dropdown triggered the modal or set a `data` attribute on the modal itself that may contain the dropdown `id` or other unique identifier. Just remember to clear out the value of the variable / data attr after submit to prevent any bugs.

**variable approach**

```
let dropdownVal = null
function handleSelect(){
  if (select.value == '-1') {
    let modal = document.getElementById('newProductModal');        
    // set some properties on the modal
    dropdownVal = -1
    $(modal).modal('show');
  }
}

document.getElementById('saveNewProduct').addEventListener('click', function (e) {  
    // some stuff  
    if(dropdownVal && dropdownVal===-1){
      document.querySelectorAll("select[id$='product']").forEach(item => {
        populateProducts(item, data.id);
      })
    }else{
     //...update pdt in dropdown 2
    }

}
```

**data-attr approach**

```
function handleSelect(){
  if (select.value == '-1') {
    let modal = document.getElementById('newProductModal');        
    // set some properties on the modal
    $(modal').data('dropdown', -1);
    $(modal).modal('show');
  }
}

document.getElementById('saveNewProduct').addEventListener('click', function (e) {  
    // some stuff  
    if($(modal).data('dropdown')===-1){
      document.querySelectorAll("select[id$='product']").forEach(item => {
        populateProducts(item, data.id);
      })
    }else{
     //...update pdt in dropdown 2
    }

}
```

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 0):

Probably a little bit late now but just in case...

Bootstrap defines a detailed event on opening/closing a modal

```
$(document).on('shown.bs.modal', '#modal-id', function (e) {
     let triggerElement = $(e.relatedTarget); // trigger
});
```

After capturing this event you could do anything you like as recommended like query for a data attribute or making an ajax request to load data properly depending on trigger.